# Checking perfomance between if(false){}else{if(false){}} and if(false){}else if(false){}

Tags: performance, if-statement

Please help checking performance between two block code bellow. I can't  I think both is the same when run-time(overlook figure element and the same condition).

```
// Block I
    if(condition1)
    {
       // Do something
    }
    else
    {    if(condition2)
        {
           // Do something
        }
        else
        {    if(condition3)
            {
               // Do something
            }
            else
            {    if(condition4)
                {
                   // Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------
    // Block II
    if(condition1)
    {
       // Do something
    }
    else  if(condition2)
    {
       // Do something
    }
    else  if(condition3)
    {
       // Do something
    }
    else  if(condition4)
    {
       // Do something
    }
```

Help me!

Comment: Put the loggers and check..

Comment: Why do you think that adding braces might make a difference?

Comment: I would consider this as premature optimization, which you shouldn't do unless you really have a performance issue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization). Additionally you might consider that it's likely that the compiler is transforming it into one of the options anyway (the compiler optimizes as well).
You program will have dozen of other places where you can win way more  performance than you can do here. If you run within some VM, your VM even might perform optimizations during runtime, depending on your actual data flows.

Comment: If there is even a difference, this would be an example of [tag:micro-optimization], i.e. the performance difference would likely be too small for it to matter for any non-trivial application.

Comment: Please tell us which language you're using - this syntax is valid in multiple languages.

Comment: Cảm ơn tất cả, tôi đã sử dụng C ++.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the language is C (you didn't specify), then you can verify that your two snippets generate *exactly* the same code by comparing the assembly output of gcc:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff <(gcc -O0 -S -o - -x c - <<EOF
extern int condition1();
extern int condition2();
extern int condition3();
extern int condition4();
extern void do_something1();
extern void do_something2();
extern void do_something3();
extern void do_something4();

void main() {
    if(condition1())
    {
       do_something1();
    }
    else
    {    if(condition2())
        {
           do_something2();
        }
        else
        {    if(condition3())
            {
               do_something3();
            }
            else
            {    if(condition4())
                {
                   do_something4();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
EOF
) <(
gcc -O0 -S -o - -x c - <<EOF
extern int condition1();
extern int condition2();
extern int condition3();
extern int condition4();
extern void do_something1();
extern void do_something2();
extern void do_something3();
extern void do_something4();

void main() {
    if(condition1())
    {
       do_something1();
    }
    else if(condition2())
    {
       do_something2();
    }
    else if(condition3())
    {
       do_something3();
    }
    else if(condition4())
    {
       do_something4();
    }
}
EOF
)
```

This generates no output (you can prove the test is valid by (e.g.) removing the last condition from one of the functions and observing that it now shows a difference).

Since the assembly language output is identical for the two blocks, you can deduce that the performance characteristics must be exactly the same.